# Set maximum and minimum values for matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, range

I have a n x 3 matrix. My column headings are longitude, latitude, and energy value.

I am trying to set an upper and limit for my 3rd column ('energy value' column) only. How do I ensure only values between 1 and 90,000 remain in that column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `m` is your matrix:

```
m[m[,3] >= 1 & m[,3] <= 90000, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other options in addition to the [answer by @Edo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594403/12158757)

```
subset(m, data.table::between(m[,3],1,90000))
```

or

```
subset(m, m[,3] >= 1 & m[,3] <= 90000)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do

```
library(dplyr)
m %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    filter(between(V3, 1, 90000))
```